# AlertDialog with switch statement in android

Tags: android, switch-statement, android-alertdialog

I'm on the way of making an android app for my client for the first time. He needs to implement multiple languages in the app. So, I put some relative layouts and while clicking it will be changed to the particular language. But now, want to put an 'alert dialog' for selection confirmation. For that, I made an alert box and implement a switch statement in the positive button. But, it's not working and I'm not having any errors.:( This is my piece of code:

```
rl_german.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        AlertDialog();; 

    }
});
rl_english.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    AlertDialog();

    }
});
  }

 private void AlertDialog()
   {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("")
        .setMessage("Are you sure you want to change the language?")
        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
        switch(which){
        case R.id.rl_english:
            startActivity(new Intent(Language.this,HomeActivity2.class));   
        break;
        case R.id.rl_german:

        break;
        case R.id.rl_french:

        break;
    }
    }
 })
.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
        // do nothing
    }
 })
 .show();
}
```

But, if I'm calling the 'startActivity' directly in my 'OnClick' method. Its working fine. Can anybody help me please. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: dismiss the dialog first and then start new activity...

Comment: Instead of Language.this use getApplicationContext() and let me know.

Comment: It's not working friends :(

Comment: See my answer. You are comparing against the wrong `id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that `which` refers to the `id` of the `Button` clicked in the `AllertDialog.Builder` (e.g. `BUTTON_POSITIVE`, `BUTTON_NEGATIVE`);

What you could do is make an `Intent` variable as a member variable (declared outside of a method) then call `startActivity()` with that variable as the parameter. Short example:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
     Intent i;

     public void onCreate(...)
     {
         ...
         rl_english.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
         i = new Intent(Language.this,HomeActivity2.class);
         AlertDialog();
      }

 private void AlertDialog()
{
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("")
    .setMessage("Are you sure you want to change the language?")
    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
        startActivity(i));
}
```

This is quick untested code so you may need to adjust for your needs, add extra code and brackets, etc... The point is, that you are trying to compare `which` to the `Button` clicked in your `Activity` but this actually refers to the `Button` clicked in your `AlertDialog`. You need to instantiate the `Intent` depending on which `Acitvity Button` is clicked then start the `Activity` if the positive `Button` in your `AlertDialog` is clicked or cancel if the negative `Button` is clicked.

Comment: Thank You Sooooo much my dear friend.. :) Actually I was little bit nervous with the problem. Since, I don't know how to solve that. You saved me.. :) Thank You!!

Answer (score 0):

I think, the problem is, your switch is working on the base of "which" parameter coming from onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which), but you are checking it with "R.id.rl_english". Your none of the cases are matching the condition because "which" gives the button clicked not the id of any view.